# How to control the order of created fields during a migration

Tags: django, django-models

I add custom fields in a model that require to be created in the order they are defined in the model. In the file created by the Django migration, this order is not respected.
Is there a way to tell Django makemigrations the order of operations ?
I use Django 1.8 and MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't any options that you can pass to the `makemigrations` command to specify the order.

However, you can reorder the operations in the migrations file that is created.

Comment: The migrations folder is in your app's directory.

Comment: If I have to create a table rows inside operations, how I can ensure that Django does not execute the next operation before inserting all the rows ?

Comment: @SidouMahmoud unless you are doing something unusual, the `RunSQL` or `RunPython` command will complete inserting the rows before the next operation starts. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question and include the code, more people will see it than in the comments here.

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair  for your reply, I found this great resource (https://blog.theodo.com/2020/05/django-migrations-without-losing-data/) it explains all the details I need.